# How to view HTTP POST values sent by arduino to php form

Tags: php

I have an arduino setup posting data to a data_post.php form online which records values to a mysql db.  The value for username is not being recorded properly in the db, it shows up as null.  The other values are fine.

When I use an html form to manually post to data_post.php, i use those echo commands currently commented out and I can see the values being posted and they are fine.  I would like to know if I can see the values being posted by the arduino setup.  But I dont know how to view that data from my server side.  The data used to work fine up until May 2019 more or less.  Is there a way to view that data?

I looked in the server logs and just found this line but it doesnt show the values because its POST, not GET:

```
2021-02-21 12:40:54 Access  205.211.254.213 200 POST /arduinostuff/data_post.php HTTP/1.0
```

Here is the php file:

```
<?php
$user = 'myusr';
$password = 'mypwd';
$server = 'localhost';
$database = 'test';
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database", $user, $password);

$username=$_POST['username'];
//echo $username;
$age=$_POST['age'];
//echo $age;
$uvindex=$_POST['uvindex'];
$mq2=$_POST['mq2'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO example (name,age,uvindex,mq2,beer) VALUES (:username, :age, :uvindex, :mq2, 'NO')";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":username", $username);
$stmt->bindParam(":age", $age);
$stmt->bindParam(":uvindex", $uvindex);
$stmt->bindParam(":mq2", $mq2);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->execute(array(':username'=>$username, ':age'=>$age, ':uvindex'=>$uvindex, ':mq2'=>$mq2));

if($result) {
    echo "Your text has been posted";
    }// end if
else {
    echo '0 results';
    }// end else
?>
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you call `$stmt->execute()` twice?

Comment: oops...thanks, thats my typo.

Comment: is other data like age,uvindex,mq2 working properly

Comment: yes, all other variables are being registered in the db just fine

Answer (score 0):

Add to your php code

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

or

```
print_r($_POST);
```

This will show every value send by POST

Comment: ok but will this show up in the server log files?

Comment: no this will show in your website like all the echos in your code, that is only for debigging purposes. this has nothing to do with the server more with php which intercepts the values

Comment: well how do I see what gets posted?  The arduino is doing the posting, so I cant see what it sees.  Thats what im trying to see, what is the arduino posting to my server.

Comment: @marciokoko it's easy to write to a file in PHP, you can Google how to do it in a few seconds. Just write the output of print_r to a file instead of into the response

Comment: hey @marciokoko to  shortout your this problem you can use `file_put_contents("test.txt",json_encode($_POST))` .